# Depending on image in PictureBox call Event

Tags: c#

I've 3 PictureBoxes. PictureBox1,PictureBox2 and PictureBox3. And I've 3 Pictures, Banana, Steak, Bread. I wanna do something like, if one of these 3 PictureBoxes has the Image of a Steak and it was clicked, it should call the Event for Steak. (It's a for Game, and this would be the Shop.) I've tried something like this:

```
    private void Buy(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox i = (PictureBox)sender;

        switch (i.Image.Tag.ToString())
        { 
            case "Steak":
                // Buy steak ... 
                break;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to be working the Tag isn't set. Question: How can I do that in C# ?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `i.Tag.ToString()`

Comment: You have to set the .Tag property, probably at the same time you set the actual image.

Comment: @Lars, my thoughts too but [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can in fact have a Tag.

Comment: So where do you set the Tag?? You should have something like `pb.Image=...; pb.Image.Tag = "Pork";` Note that while you can set the `Image` in the designer, you have to set the `Image.Tag` in code, maybe in the `Form.Load` event..

Comment: @TaW My "guess" was that the OP was setting the Tag property of the PictureBox, hence my comment.  OP needs to show us more code obviously.

Comment: Of course, although I suspect that there isn't more code outside the designer.cs. Just wanted to spell it out about `Image.Tag`, since I hadn't even suspected it..

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry for late answer. Your first comment did what I want. :) Thanks.